AWS ECR login using awscli and docker cli
I'm trying to execute a bash that logins to AWS, and it builds, tags and pushes a docker image, here's my bash file content:
aws ecr get-login-password --region us-east-2 --profile weather_ecr_agent | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin <LOGIN>
docker build -f ./Dockerfile -t cloud-weather-temperature: latest .
docker tag cloud-weather-temperature: latest <LOGIN>/cloud-weather-temperature: latest 
docker push <LOGIN>/cloud-weather-temperature:latest

Whenever I try to execute the bash file on CLI using the following cmd :
bash build_and_push_ecr_image.sh
i get the following error:
   build_and_push_ecr_image.sh: /mnt/c/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/Scripts/aws: C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
Error: Cannot perform an interactive login from a non TTY device
ERROR: "docker buildx build" requires exactly 1 argument.
See 'docker buildx build --help'.

Usage:  docker buildx build [OPTIONS] PATH | URL | -

Start a build
"docker tag" requires exactly 2 arguments.
See 'docker tag --help'.

Usage:  docker tag SOURCE_IMAGE[:TAG] TARGET_IMAGE[:TAG]

Create a tag TARGET_IMAGE that refers to SOURCE_IMAGE
invalid reference format

NOTE: AWSCLI is installed using pip
aws-cli/1.34.22 Python/3.9.7 Windows/10 botocore/1.35.22


As you've shown the script, there are extra spaces around the tag name; docker build -t cloud-weather-temperature:latest should not have a space before latest.  Is this your problem?  (You can run the docker build and docker tag commands without doing anything AWS-related, do you have the same problem if you take AWS out of the picture?)

From your text aws-cli/1.34.22 Python/3.9.7 Windows/10 botocore/1.35.22 I figured you were trying to run bash on windows. What bash were you using? When you type wsl --version on your terminal, what do you see? Do you have WSL installed?
You can try install it and install a linux distro inside it. If you want the easier way and just want to get things working really quickly, just use the windows equivalent login method instead. You can find them on you AWS console, open ECR, click on the image you created, click View push commands, toggle the part for windows.
It looks something like
(Get-ECRLoginCommand).Password | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin XXXXXXXXXXXX.xxx.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com

The rest of the docker commands are the same.
You will then need to create a powershell script instead of bash script.
